# javascript comparison crises

Tags: javascript, comparison

I came across the following and was unable to grasp the reason, can anyone explain please?

```
var foo = [0];
console.log(foo == !foo); // true 
console.log(foo == foo);  // true
```

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat :-)

Comment: As a side note - in JavaScript you will usually get unexpected results when using == as a comparison.  You should always use === instead since it doesn't use type conversion.

Comment: Type coercion: http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

Comment: @PhillipKregg So we can always use === instead of == ?

Comment: @Ansu - that's what Crockford recommends.  It's a safe bet to always use === unless you have a specific reason not to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second comparison is simple to explain: `foo` is equal to itself.

The first one, however, is a bit tricky: `foo` is an array, which is an object, which evaluates to `true` when [coerced to boolean](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9). So `!foo` is `false`. But `foo` on the left side of the comparison is not being converted to boolean. Both operands are actually converted to numbers during the equality comparison. This is how it evaluates:

```
[0] == false
[0] == 0
"0" == 0
0 == 0
true
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), on comparisons with the equality operator `==`:

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible

I know this explanation sounds superficial. It's actually much more complicated than that, but the basic steps are the ones I listed above. You can see the details on the ECMA-262 specification, particularly on sections [9](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9) and [11.9](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9).

Answer (score -1):

You should use "===" and "!==" instead of "==" and "!="
More explanations there:
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-10-javascript-mistakes-youre-making/

Comment: He's not asking what to do instead, he's trying to wrap his head around what causes this.

Comment: Yes and the first link gives the explanation